# $(1-t^2)^2 = 1-2t^2 + t^4$ . Why $+ t^4$?

Tags: involutions

Understand that involution means to multiply value with the same value so many times as involution number.
So, understand that $1*1=1$

<strike>$t^2 * t^2$ would be 2t^2</strike> (sorry, now understand that this is incorrect. Should be $t^{(2+2)}$ because rule is that for multiplication must sum the exponents).

So far understand.

But why $+ t^4$?

What the rule determines that need $+ t^4$?

If instead t use some number, then yes, all is correct.
Just want to understand why $+ t^4$?

What would need to do if, for example $(1-t^2)^4$ or $(1-t^3)^2$ ?

[image]

Here is link to "textbook" https://estudijas.rtu.lv/pluginfile.php/287370/mod_resource/content/0/Uzdevumi/Uzdevumi_1.pdf The first page, the first example (1. piemērs. Aprēķināt / 1.example. Must calculate)

Comment: Uhh... $t^2 \times t^2 = t^4$. You might double check your algebra textbook.

Comment: You should look up “rules of exponents”, “FOIL method”, and perhaps “binomial theorem” for more complicated examples

Comment: There seem to be several things you are doing wrong.  First, recall that $(a+b)^2 = (a+b)\times (a+b)$.  Next, recall that $(a+b)\times (c+d) = a\times c + a\times d + b\times c + b\times d$.  Third, recall that $x^a\times x^b = x^{a+b}$.  You seem to have been multiplying in some cases and adding when variables were involved instead of multiplying, you seem to have been trying to "distribute exponentiation over addition" rather than correctly expanding as a product of sums, and other errors

Comment: Do you know how to expand the square? That is, do you know what $(a + b)^2$ and $(a - b)^2$ expand to? If not, that might be something you should look into.

Comment: $(1-t^2)^2 = (1 - t^2)(1 - t^2) = 1(1 - t^2) - t^2(1 - t^2) = 1*1 - 1*t^2 - t^2*1 - t^2*(-t^2) = 1 - t^2 - t^2 + t^2*t^2 = 1 - 2t^2 + t^4$. Because squaring is iterated multiplication, the distributive law, the distributive law, properties of 1 and sign arithmetic, simplification and the aforementioned fact that $t^2*t^2 = t^4$.

Comment: As for "*what to do for $(1-t^2)^4$*" you should see the binomial theorem.  It will be $(1-t^2)^4=1-4t^2+6t^4-4t^6+t^8$

Comment: See [The Freshman's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream) for an explanation on why $(x+y)^n = x^n+y^n$ is wrong, why you can't just distribute exponentiation over addition.  See [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) for why $x^a\times x^b = x^{a+b}$ and so why $(t^2)^2 = t^4\neq 2t^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the binomial formula we have $(1-t^2)^2=1-2 \times t^2+{(t^2)}^2=1-2t^2+t^{2 \times 2}=1-2t^2+t^4$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So as i understand i must learn binominal formula... uhhhh

Comment: Its more useful than you may think now. ;)